# Only allow .git clone on local machine

Tags: git, security

I have a private .git repo  on a centOS machine. Last week I realized that I had my .git folder exposed on my public_html directory. There's no evidence of intrusion but I was always taught to assume the worst.

I've removed the directory. If someone had downloaded my .git directory, what could they continue to do with it? Can they clone my source code forever? What would be the best way to block future clonings of that repository?

Since all development is on one server anyways, I thought one solution would be to block cloning or checking out from any remote machine (ie only allow cloning locally). Is this possible?

EDIT: my config file does not contain user or token.

Comment: Verify that your .git/config file doesn't contain access token / username..

Comment: What do you mean by continue to clone it? Cloning the downloaded repo? Of course the can. Clone an updated version of your repo: No!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There's no evidence of intrusion but I was always taught to assume the worst.

You may want to check your webservers acces-log, it should have entries for this directory if it was accessed through the web.

> I've removed the directory. If someone had downloaded my .git directory, what could they continue to do with it? Can they clone my source code forever?

No, of course not. When it's gone (moved to another place), its gone.

> What would be the best way to block future clonings of that repository?

Don't use a web-accessible directory (aka a directory under the document-root of your webserver) for git-repositorys (or rather for anything which shouldn't be publicly accessible). Just use your home-directory for your own, private files.

> Since all development is on one server anyways, I thought one solution would be to block cloning or checking out from any remote machine (ie only allow cloning locally). Is this possible?

Git itself has no such feature, but as long as one can not access your *git-directory*, one can not clone it. Therefore, if you keep your private git-repository in your home-directory (assuming the home-directory isn't your document-root) then nobody will be able to clone the git-repository, unless they have access to your account (can connect to ssh with your credentials, for example) or root-permissions on that server.